# How do I cast a socket to my handler class?

Tags: c#, sockets

I created a handler class which extends the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class. I am not familiar with casting types, inheritance or C# for that matter, so how do I cast a regular Socket to my Handler class?

I've tried this:

```
Handler handler = (Handler)socket;
```

But I get an InvalidCastException. Also, I do not want to extend the class by using a container class.

Thanks.

Comment: nobody can give you a real answer without seeing at least the declaration of your `Handler` class...

Comment: I suppose this is my declaration: class Handler : Socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just can't, that's not how inheritance works.

You can't treat some `Socket` as your `Handler`. It works the other way around: you can treat your `Handler` as a `Socket`.

If you want to use your `Handler`, you need to create an instance of it, by using something like `new Handler()`.